# Issue with Google chart within Sencha Touch Carousel

Tags: sencha-touch-2, google-visualization

I hava a google gauge chart within a sencha carousel and the chart is updated within a time interval. At first when carousel painted it works fine. But the problem is that, when I make carousel swipe and come back again then the chart cause error.

Here is the view:

```
Ext.define('GGraphSencha.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Carousel',
    xtype: 'main',
    name: 'mainview',
    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            id: 'gaugegraph'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'line 1'          
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'line 2'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'line 2'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'line 2'
        }]
    }
});
```

and here is the controller:

```
Ext.define('GGraphSencha.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        refs: {
            mainview: {
                xtype: 'mainview',
                selector: 'mainview',
                autoCreate: true
            },
            gauge: 'gaugegraph',
        },
        control: {

        }
    },
    getDataForGauge: function() {
        return [['', Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + 1]];
    },
    gaugeData: null,
    gaugeChart: null,
    interval: null,
    getOptionsForGauge: function() {
        return {
            //width: 500 ,
            height: 170,
            greenFrom: 0,
            greenTo: 30,
            redFrom: 60,
            redTo: 100,
            yellowFrom: 30,
            yellowTo: 60,
            minorTicks: 5
        };
    },
    launch: function() {
        var me = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            me.drawGauge();
        }, 1000);
        this.interval = setInterval(function() {
            me.updateGauge();
        }, 5000);
    },

    drawGauge: function() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        this.gaugeData = data;
        this.gaugeData.addColumn('string', 'Label');
        this.gaugeData.addColumn('number', 'Value');
        this.gaugeData.addRows(this.getDataForGauge());
        this.gaugeChart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gaugegraph'));
        this.gaugeChart.draw(this.gaugeData, this.getOptionsForGauge());
    },
    updateGauge: function() {
        this.gaugeData.setValue(0, 1, Math.round(Math.random() * 100 + 1));
        this.gaugeChart.draw(this.gaugeData, this.getOptionsForGauge());
    }
});
```

Please help me with some solution.

Thanks....

Comment: What is the error? You should put the chart logic inside your view, not the controller. And also only update the chart when the view is painted.

Comment: it is not necessary to end all your questions in "thanks....", can you please refrain from this in the future?